# Unable to make it a bootable background service

Tags: android

I've made simple App( for Android 5+) to detect specific SMS and forward to remote server and it will **not** be published in Google Play.

I want to make it a service which runs on start/reboot and keeps running in background.

I've declared needed permissions in AndroidManifest.xml But it works after boot only in my Oneplus. In other mobiles it does not work after restart or close it
. **What have I missed**?:

**BgService.java:**

```
public class AnuServiceService {
    public AnuServiceService () {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       

        new OTPReceiver();

        return START_STICKY;
    }
.....
}
```

**BootCompleteReceiver**:

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "BootCompleteReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      
       
       
            Intent i = new Intent(context, OTPReceiver.class);
            context.startService(i);
        }
    }
```

**OTPReceiver**:

```
public class OTPReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Handler mHandler;
    Handler otp_visibility_handler;
    Runnable otp_runnable;


    public void setEditText_otp(EditText editText) {
        // OTPReceiver
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        SmsMessage[] smsMessages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        int slot = bundle.getInt("slot", -1);
        int sub = bundle.getInt("subscription", -1);


        Gson gson = new Gson();
        class NewObj {
        ..................
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.op">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <service
            android:name=".AnuService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"></service>

        <activity android:name=".SMSForwardNumber" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>





        <receiver  android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>




        <receiver
            android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".OTPReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to make it a service which runs on start/reboot and keeps running in background.

Not possible in any modern version of Android - it needs to be a foreground service. That said, the `SMS_RECEIVED` action is exempt from the restrictions around [implicit broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions), so you should be able to just define it in your manifest only. No need for your boot receiver or service. Just use your `OTPReceiver`.

**Edit:**
Keep in mind that you'll need to account for dynamic permissions as well. Specifying the `RECEIVE_SMS` permission in your manifest isn't enough; you'll also need to add code to prompt for the permission if the user hasn't allowed it.

You can enable the permission manually from the settings page for your app, or add the `-g` flag if you install your app via ADB.

Comment: Sorry i'm a beginner, if you can help with code it'd be nice

Comment: Just delete everything except for your `OTPReceiver`. A new incoming SMS should wake up your app and call your receiver for this alone. You can test it easily enough with logging in the `onReceive` callback. If the amount of logic you need to run is short, you can do it diretly in `onReceive` - otherwise, start a new "job" with a work manager and use that. Oh, you may also need to ensure you've enabled permissions for your app as well.

Comment: Dynamic permissions came with Android M I believe. It's possible to write it in a backwards compatible way though.

Comment: can u tell if two messeges received on 2 sims at the same time on dual SIM what will happen? It seems with this one SMS is not being caught.

Comment: I don't know, sorry. That isn't something I have experience with.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, Broadcast receivers can be enabled this way:

in `BootCompleteReceiver` try:

```
public ComponentName otpReceiver = new ComponentName(context, OTPReceiver.class)
  context.packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
    otpReceiver,
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to receive BOOT_COMPLETED, the user must run the app once manually after the installation unless the app is located in /system/priv-app.

Second, you cannot create the background service directly in a background broadcast receiver like your BOOT_COMPLETED receiver since Android Oreo. It seems that your manifest and service class is ok, although they have something to improve. Please refer: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // the following line should be Intent i = new Intent(context, AnuServiceService.class), isn't it?
        Intent i = new Intent(context, OTPReceiver.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

This does not start service on Android 8+. Instead of this, use startForegroundService(): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startForegroundService(android.content.Intent).

Or in your case, just create an activity class that starts the service and then call finish(). Next, invoke startActivity(the activity you created) in the broadcast receiver. I checked that it works on Android O.